If a space is covered by two closed zero-dimensional subsets, is the space zero-dimensional?
Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, $C_0, C_1 \subset X$ be closed and zero-dimensional, and $C_0 \cup C_1 = X$.
Is $\mathcal{T}$ zero-dimensional?
Notes

A space is zero-dimensional, if it has a basis of clopen subsets.
This result is true if we assume that $\mathcal{T}$ is a separable metric space.
Here we are not assuming anything from $\mathcal{T}$, so there's probably a counterexample.


Is it really true, if $X$ is normal $T_2$? This is well-known to hold for strong zero-dimensionality, so yes for separable metric spaces.

That the result holds for normal Hausdorff spaces is stated in the book "Theory of Dimensions: Finite and Infinite" by Engelking, page 16, Remark 1.3.2. which precedes the proof of the corresponding Theorem 1.3.1 for separable metric spaces. I have not checked the proof in detail though. In this theorem he uses a characterization of zero-dimensionality as follows: for each closed subsets $A$ and $B$ exists open subsets $U$ and $V$ such that $A \subset U$, $B \subset V$, $U \cup V = X$, and $U \cap V = \emptyset$, which resembles a stronger form of normality.

There are many different alternative characterizations of zero-dimensionality based on what assumptions are available which are not equivalent over all spaces, but only over some restricted class of spaces, such as normal spaces here.

Also I'm not sure whether the theorem needs Hausdorffness at all. I threw it in because I know the book assumes it, and did not want to check whether I can omit it.

the property you cite from Engelking's book is exactly "ultranormal", which is equivalent to normal + strongly zero dimensional. Hence, this does not imply the zero-dimensional case (also assuming everything is $T_2$).

I see. The remark actually states that if you cover a space by countably many closed ultranormal subsets, then the space is ultranormal. But ultranormal is not equivalent to zero-dimensionality over normal spaces, just over separable metric spaces.

I haven't checked it, but Engelking, General topology, 7.2.C should be a counter-example: as stated there, $X$ is normal (which includes $T_2$), not zero-dimensional, but yet covered by two closed, zero-dimensional subspaces.

Nice find. I've yet to check it.
